# How do I add a second animation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement an image zooming effect (because it's in a container with overflow:hidden, increasing it's width and sliding it left should do the trick).

I've managed to make it increase it's width:

```
/* Zoom in images */
$('img.vectimg').load(function() {
    $(this).data('width', this.width);
}).bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: $(this).data('width') * (e.type === 'mouseenter' ?  1.2 : 1)
    });
});
```

But how can I add the animation for moving it to left?
I tried appending this / but it haven't worked.

```
$(this).stop().animate({
            left: $(this).position().left  + 500
        });
```

I'm a complete newbie so please don't take me hard :)

Comment: Your elements **position** must be set to **relative** before you change its position using jQuery callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple properties in the same `animate()` call.

```
$(this).stop().animate({
    width: $(this).data('width') * (e.type === 'mouseenter' ?  1.2 : 1),
    left: $(this).position().left + (e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 500 : -500)
});
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: this will cause it to continually shift right on mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: right, but it's an *example* of how to add multiple properties to an animate call... what the OP then does to make it fit in with their code is up to them. They seem to be comfortable with ternary operators so I'm sure this won't be a roadblock for them.

Comment: thnks for the answer but how can I make `left: $(this).position().left + 500` do the right thing

Comment: @slownage - *"do the right thing"* doesn't help me try and figure out your problem... I've added a ternary operator (the same as you have for `width`)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `animate()` callback function for next animation.

Check out documentation [here.](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

**Note**: You must set your element's `position` to `relative` (in CSS) in order to manipulate left, right properties etc.